# What's the proper way of mounting surge arresters on TN-S system?

Tags: ac, grounding, circuit-protection, surge-protection

I'm attaching a diagram with surge arresters put on each line. Most of the experts in the field say a proper defense against lightnings and switching events has three surge arresters - one between phase and ground, one between neutral and ground, and one between phase and neutral. So what is the proper way of connecting the surge arrester between phase and neutral?

[image]

Comment: Why not check the datasheet of the surge arrester?

Comment: There is no datasheet showing how to mount it between phase and ground or if it's allowed ...

Comment: If you have a specific model in mind, include a link to it, and if possible a datasheet. Manufacturers datasheet should be followed.

Comment: If you don't have a datasheet, then you don't know what you have purchased.

Comment: Do you even need one between line and neutral if you have some going to ground? In an over voltage condition on line or neutral the overvoltage current would be sent to ground, and not be a problem. I would think that if there is an overvoltage on line, you wouldn't want to send it back to neutral.

Comment: Start with this document and then get and read the guides it references: http://apps.geindustrial.com/publibrary/checkout/Arresters?TNR=White%20Papers%7CArresters%7Cgeneric

Comment: What I understood about having an arrester between line and neutral is that if the ground is faulty and neutral is separated from ground, then the spikes will go through the neutral. So the question is still relevant - is it safe to have a surge arrester between phase(line) and neutral

Comment: @rdtsc If you have something in mind then give an example of datasheet from Schneider, General Electric or ABB. Their pdfs don't offer an info about the case, they just say some general advices